# How can I set some default settings for JMS Translation?

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I have installed JMS translation for my Symfony2 project. I managed to extract the translation files successfully.

What I need now is to find a way to set some default values, so that when I call the command I will not need to set every time  the excluded directories or the filename.

Is this possible? Maybe through the services.yml or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you will find some example configuration http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSTranslationBundle/master/cookbook/extraction_configs

> Once you have found a suitable combination of command line options, it
>   might be a bit tedious to specify them each time when you want to run
>   the extraction command. For this, you can also set-up some pre-defined
>   settings via the configuration: